# Problema con esta función para modificar archivos en C

Tags: c, archivo

Para este ejercicio tuve que crear un archivo con 5 registros de alumnos que contiene: Nombre del alumno, fecha de ingreso a la universidad, carrera en curso, y promedio en la carrera.

Lo que me piden en el ejercicio es crear una funcion para que todos los alumnos que tengan "Ingenieria" como carrera pasen a tener "Informatica". En total son 3 alumnos con "Ingenieria" como carrera, pero al hacer la funcion, solamente cambia el texto del primer alumno, dejando a los otros 2 sin modificar.

Mi pregunta es por qué solamente se actualiza un solo registro pero los demás permanecen igual. El programa no me tira errores ni warnings al momento de compilar.

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define TAM 5

typedef struct {
int dd,
    mm,
aa;}
t_fecha;

typedef struct {
char NyA[50];
t_fecha fing;
char carrera [30];
float promGral;}t_alumno; //SON LAS ESTRUCTURAS CON LAS QUE DEFINO EL ARCHIVO

void reemplazaDatos (FILE *archivo)
{
FILE *pf=archivo;
t_alumno alumno[TAM];
int i;

fopen("alumnos.dat","r+");
if (!pf) exit(1);

for (i=0;i<TAM;i++)
{
fread(&alumno,sizeof alumno,1,pf);
if(strcmp(alumno[i].carrera,"Ingenieria")==0)
{
strcpy(alumno[i].carrera,"Informatica");
}
}

fclose(pf);

fopen("alumnos.dat","w+");
if (!pf) exit(1);

for (i=0;i<TAM;i++)
{
fwrite(&alumno,sizeof alumno,1,pf);
}
fclose(pf);
}

int main()
{
t_alumno alumno[TAM]={{"Juan Perez",{1,5,2010},"Ingenieria",7.50},{"Ana Lopez",{4,7,2011},"Abogacia",8.0},{"Jose Ramirez",{9,10,2012},"Ingenieria",9.14},{"Camilo Sanchez",{16,9,2013},"Ingenieria",7.6},{"Julia Fernandez",{30,6,2010},"Medicina",7.81}};
//El primer, el tercer y el cuarto alumno tienen "Ingeniería" como carrera
int i;
FILE *pf;
pf=fopen("alumnos.dat","wb");
if (!pf) exit(1);
fwrite(alumno, sizeof(t_alumno), TAM, pf);
fclose(pf);
reemplazaDatos(pf);
pf=fopen("alumnos.dat","rb");
if (!pf) exit(1);
for (i=0;i<TAM;i++)
fread(alumno,sizeof(t_alumno),1,pf);
printf("\nRegistro %d %s %d %d %d %s %.2f",i+1, alumno[i].NyA, alumno[i].fing.dd, alumno[i].fing.mm, alumno[i].fing.aa, alumno[i].carrera, alumno[i].promGral);

//el for ya terminó. no me toma las llaves
fclose(pf);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edita y formatea  el código.

Comment: Eso que muestras **no es un código válido en C**, *ergo* no puede actualizar ningún registro, *ergo* **no está claro lo que preguntas**. Si esperas un mínimo esfuerzo por parte de alguien al responderte, es justo requerir *de tu parte* un mínimo esfuerzo al preguntar. Un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sería una prueba perfecta de ello. De momento, voto por cerrarla.

Comment: Ya se cuál es tu problema: tu código no compila.

Answer (score 1):

Solo te cambia el primero porque solo estas leyendo el primer alumno del fihcero.
Prueba a añadir en la funcion reemplazardatos

```
fopen("alumnos.dat","r+");
if (!pf) exit(1);
while(!feof(pf)
{
 for (i=0;i<TAM;i++)
 {
  fread(&alumno,sizeof alumno,1,pf);
  if(strcmp(alumno[i].carrera,"Ingenieria")==0)
  {
      strcpy(alumno[i].carrera,"Informatica");
  }
 }
}
fclose(pf);
```

Ese while lo que hara sera repetir el proceso del bucle hasta que se llegue al final del fichero, asi compararas todos los alumnos y no se te cambiará solo el del primero

Espero que te funcione :))